# I get the ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when access my site with www

Tags: dns, apache2, subdomain, ubuntu-20.04

I have a little problem with my domain configuration. When I try to access my site with [www.something.com](http://www.something.com) I get this error in browser:

> This site can’t provide a secure connection
> [www.something.com](http://www.something.com) sent an invalid response.
> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

This is my Zone File configuration

```
; A Records
*       IN  A   server IPv4 address
@       IN  A   server IPv4 address
www     IN  A   server IPv4 address
; AAAA Records
*       IN  AAAA    server IPv6 address
@       IN  AAAA    server IPv6 address
www     IN  AAAA    server IPv6 address
```

This is my .cnf file for ssl

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName something.com
        SSLEngine on
        ServerAdmin mail@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/app/public
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/app/public/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/errorSSL.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/accessSSL.log combined
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        ServerAlias www.app.com
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

It works without www. (eg. https://something.com/) but it doesn't work with www (eg. https://www.something.com/)

Any idea what could it be? Or what am I doing wrong?

I tried to create a .cnf file with www for enable-sites but without success. I added the [www.something.com](http://www.something.com) in hosts on server but no success. I tried to add a redirect in apache2.cnf file for www to not www domain but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Add `ServerAlias www.something.com`.

Comment: Note: are you sure you want the DNS wildcard resource record? The one with `*`. Unless your SSL certificate is a wildcard certificate, clients will receive TLS errors for anything other than `something.com` and `www.something.com`.

Comment: @JohnHanley there is ServerAlias already, and i tried with and without wildcard, but the behaviour is the same.

Comment: 1) Update your post so that the configuration in your post is what you are actually using. 2) Remove the DNS wildcard so that you are not solving more than one problem at a time. 3) Did you enable SSL? The command is `a2enmod ssl`.